# how to keep position of rotated tables

Tags: floats, rotating, r, knitr, xtable

Since I'm working with R, I'm using the `xtable` package to produce my tables in Latex. Some of the tables only fit the page if rotated. It seems that `sidewaystable` always starts a new page. My problem now is, that the order of the sections is wrong. The rotated table starts at a new page but the section which should appear after the rotated table is now printed directly after the second section. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\section{first}

<<table1,echo=FALSE,results='asis',message=FALSE>>=
require(xtable)
t1 <- xtable(data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10)))
print(t1)
@

\section{second}

<<table2,echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
t2 <- xtable(data.frame(z=rnorm(20),y=rnorm(20),x=rnorm(20)))
print(t2,floating.environment="sidewaystable")
@

\section{third}

<<table3,echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
t3 <- xtable(data.frame(z=rnorm(20),y=rnorm(20),x=rnorm(20)))
print(t3,floating.environment="sidewaystable")
@


\end{document}
```

What I'd like to have is:

1. the tables to stay at the right position
2. no start of a new page (table 2 should be printed in horizontal mode on the same page as table 1 is printed if it fits. If there isn't enough space left over for the whole table to be printed, it should be printed on the next page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the rotating package creates page floats (i.e., they occupy the whole height of the page); the "incorrect ordering" is no more than the usual problem with page floats ordering.  probably the best you can do is hand- construct the interaction between tables and text, and do away with floats altogether.  not what you wanted to be told, no doubt, but that's the way it is.

Comment: Using `\rotatebox{90}{yourtablehere}` from the `graphicx` package would rotate the table without creating a page in landscape mode. The position of the float should be dealt with in the usual tecnhiques.

Comment: thanks, but this gives me an error. the rotatebox-command should be inside the table environment right? I don't know how to achieve this within xtable. There's an Option Floating.Environment. But that doesn't work either here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that R tables are also floats, so you need include the `floating=F` option. Then the R chunks can be turned or rotated as showed in the MWE:

A problem with this is that the caption cannot be generated by R in no floatings tables, and `\caption` or `\captionof` of package `caption` cannot be placed inside a rotating object, but you can put the rotate object in a float an then use `\rotcaption`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\section{Turning}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{.05\linewidth}
\rotcaption{Turned  90\textdegree}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.8\linewidth}
\begin{turn}{90}
<<table1,echo=F,results=tex>>=
require(xtable)
print(xtable(data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10)),caption="x"),floating=F)
@
\end{turn}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\section{Rotating}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{.05\linewidth}
\rotcaption{Rotated 90\textdegree}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.8\linewidth}
\rotatebox{90}{
<<tablex,echo=F,results=tex>>=
print(xtable(data.frame(z=rnorm(20),y=rnorm(20),x=rnorm(20))),floating=F)
@
}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```